# Load external library in a sepcific page using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am using angularjs for my web application, I wanted to load google maps specific javascript file only in a particular page, anybody help me to do that?

Corresponding JS File: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true

I tried to place this JS file in my page specific template which is throwing me an error like 'd.init is not a function', but that's working fine if I load that JS file in my index.html.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, so anybody please suggest me on this??

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main controller

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            if(toState.name == 'somePage'){
              $scope.googlesrc = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/....'
            } else {
              $scope.googlesrc = ''
            }
        });
```

in your html

```
  <script ng-src="{{googlesrc}}"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like a good idea, will try and update in sometime since I am away from my laptop now.

Comment: @SPACEATZ, sorry for the delayed response here, actually I tried your approach and worked fine. I was not completely satisfied by this approach perhaps we are going to have an unwanted blank script tag for many pages. So I got another option to handle this scenario after some more research, that is 'ocLazyLoad' which allows us to include route specific resources. You can check https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/with-your-router if you are interested to know more.

Comment: Marked this as the correct answer perhaps this approach resolved the issue, for a better solution please refer my previous comment.